# Upgrade php to same main version

Tags: centos, upgrade, php

I need to upgrade php on working server from `7.2.14` to `7.2.19`

`yum list installed php*` shows only `7.2.14-1.el7.remi` exist within installed packages.

I can't use `yum update` neither `yum upgrade` since this will upgrade pages I need them within their current versions.

OS: Centos7

Comment: AFAIK remi will limit the PHP to the same 7.2.x version. It should never go to PHP7.3. Could you post the output of a `yum update php*`?

Comment: @Edward `yum update php*` is going to update php and its dependencies, which is the thing I don't want, I need just to update php alone to that version.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt you can update *ONLY* php base package. The remaining (excluded) packages will still depend on an older version, e.g. for `php-json`:

```
» yum deplist php-json
package: php-json.x86_64 7.1.30-1.el7.remi
<...>
  dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.30-1.el7.remi
   provider: php-common.x86_64 7.1.30-1.el7.remi
<...>
```

^ you see the dependency on `php-common`?

If I tried this: `yum update php --exclude=php-json` I would get:

```
--> Processing Dependency: php-json(x86-64) = 7.1.30-1.el7.remi for package: php-common-7.1.30-1.el7.remi.x86_64
Error: Package: php-common-7.1.30-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
           Requires: php-json(x86-64) = 7.1.30-1.el7.remi
           Installed: php-json-7.1.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
               php-json(x86-64) = 7.1.29-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-json(x86-64)
           Available: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-json(x86-64) = 1.3.10
           Available: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-json(x86-64) = 1.3.10
           Removing: php-common-7.1.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
               Not found
           Updated By: php-common-7.1.30-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-8.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-9.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               Not found
Error: Package: php-json-7.1.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.29-1.el7.remi
           Removing: php-common-7.1.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php71)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.29-1.el7.remi
           Updated By: php-common-7.1.30-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php71)
               php-common(x86-64) = 7.1.30-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.el7
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-8.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-8.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.6.40-9.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-9.el7.remi
```

going around in circles...

Comment: Can't I just build it from the source code?